# extracting the favicon from a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, favicon

I am trying extract the favicon from the website url. I am using `HtmlAgilityPack`. I get some favicons but not all. I think the problem is variation in implementation. Current strategy of mine is..

```
        HtmlNode imageNode = head.SelectSingleNode("//link[@rel='shortcut icon' or @rel='apple-touch-icon' or @rel='icon' or @rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed'] | //link[@type='image/png' or @type='image/gif' or @type='image/vnd.microsoft.icon']");

        imageNode = head.SelectSingleNode("link[@rel='image_src']");
```

and the open graph method

```
          private LinkDetails GetOpenGraphInfo(LinkDetails linkDetails, HtmlNode head)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode headNode in head.ChildNodes)
    {
        switch (headNode.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "link": break;

            case "meta":
                if (headNode.Attributes["property"] != null && headNode.Attributes["content"] != null)
                {
                    switch (headNode.Attributes["property"].Value.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "og:title":
                            linkDetails.Title = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;
                        case "og:type":
                            linkDetails.Type = headNode.Attributes["content"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "og:url":
                            linkDetails.Url = headNode.Attributes["content"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "og:image":
                            linkDetails.Image = new ImageLink(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value, linkDetails.Url);
                            break;
                        case "og:site_name":
                            linkDetails.SiteName = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;
                        case "og:description":
                            linkDetails.Description = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;
                        case "og:email":
                            linkDetails.Email = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;
                        case "og:phone_number":
                            linkDetails.PhoneNumber = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;
                        case "og:fax_number":
                            linkDetails.FaxNumber = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(headNode.Attributes["content"].Value);
                            break;

                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    return linkDetails;
}
```

but still I am missing some favicons. So I need to know how else are the favicon coded.

Comment: I don't get this. Why do you need the favicons?

Comment: that is another issue.. Say I need them for bookmarking...

Answer (score 3):

Go to the link below to download the favicon for a website.

Open the link and click save as image to download it.

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=codegena.com

**Replace codegena.com with the domain name for which you want to download the favicon.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://yourblog.com/favicon.png" />
```

and

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Actually, the correct method to add a favicon is via a Plugin, so that the added favicon is not Theme-dependent.

Also you may be missing some file types.

Comment: Sorry you did not understand the question.. I want to extract the favicons of other websites I am browsing..

Comment: That is why I am telling you the ways in which favicon is put into a website. why don't you extract the web url along with the favicons so that you can see from which url the favicon is not getting extracted. Then see the method in those urls

Comment: Yes I am doing that but still clueless... like check this website and tell me how they are doing this .. I am unable to find how they are doing this.. http://www.bhvr.com/en/

Comment: yes got it... but how the browser get this method.. I will have to do quite tedious work to get this ..

Comment: yes because what you are doing is not a simple task and cannot be fully accomplished always.